# How to evaluate which perl is running at Windows machine

Tags: windows, perl, version

I need to evaluate which Perl for Windows is running at a machine I have got remote access to.
I already used

```
perl -v
```

and

```
perl -V
```

which gives me already the version number etc.
But how can I find out, if it is ActiveState Perl or Strawberry Perl or something else?
My first guess at the moment is, that I am just blind or something...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is like asking is it centos, suse or debian perl?

Comment: But I need to know how it was compiled to install the correct module... If it is a pure perl module... sure... no problem, but if it has c-compiled parts, i need to know how it was compiled to get the correct module-version. Or am I mistaken? If so, can you please explain where I am mistaken? Thanks

Comment: @Diskilla then you don't want to know whether it's strawberry or activestate; you want to know the info about how it was compiled. That's in `Config` under entries like `$Config{cc}`, `$Config{cflags}`, `$Config{ld}`, etc. All of which also shows up under `perl -V`.

Comment: @Diskilla if you use this information properly then you can build for *any* perl, not just those two. And see also ExtUtils::CBuilder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -V:myuname
perl -MConfig -e "print $Config{myuname}"
```

output

```
Win32 strawberryperl 5.10.1.2 #1 Wed Apr 28 11:51:06 2010 i386
```

Comment: I found another solution which is shorter.
perl -e 'print $^O'

Comment: @Diskilla I'm afraid that `$^O` doesn't know about Strawberry vs Activestate.

Comment: Yeah. You are right. It only tells the OS. I'm going to edit the comment to correct it. Thanks. (Edit: No i won't. I can't anymore...)